# Efficiently selecting every nth row from SQL table where n is not integer

Tags: sql-server, select, filtering, sql-server-2014

I have come up with a way of selecting `@numRows-2` evenly spaced rows from `@totalCount` rows (more or less) (pseudo code in {} brackets, same description means same code):

```
declare @numRows int
set @numRows = {how many rows I want}

declare @totalCount bigint
select @totalCount = count(1) from {table}
where {filter condition on indexed rows}

declare @mult float
set @mult = 0.999999999 * (@numRows - 2) / (@totalCount - 1)

select ts.rownum, --debug only
        ts.{other data},
        ...
from
(
    select  {other data},
            ...,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY {ordering}) as rownum
    from {table}
    where {filter condition on indexed rows}
) as ts
where round(@mult * ts.rownum, 0) <> round((ts.rownum + 1) * @mult, 0)
order by {ordering}
```

(the 0.99999... factor is to get around what I am guessing is float rounding errors causing an extra row to be returned - and is part of why I am searching for a better algorithm).

Examples of results:

100 from 200: every 2nd row

200 from 500: skip 2, then 3, then 2, and so on

100 from 100: everything returned

100 rows from 50: everything returned

I'm not convinced it is the most efficient way to perform this kind of filtering, but I can't come up with a better way.  I have found SQL answers that do something similar, but not the same, and non-SQL answers that do exactly this, but are not set-based.

Assuming there is nothing in the table data itself (e.g. an identity column) that might help with the query, I was wondering if there is generally a more efficient way to do this.  I'm open to temporary result tables.

In case this is interesting/relevant: This is on a fanless embedded PC with SSD, 4C Celeron 1.8GHz, SQL Server 2014 express, max 500MB ram allocated to SQL.  Typically `@numRows=2`,000 and `@totalCount=100`,000 to 1,000,000.  It's for timeseries resampling.

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me, it's too long and there is no specific question that I can see.  What do you want help with?

Comment: @MHJ, I was after a more efficient way of implementing the 'every nth record' filter, which is currently being performed by the line "where round(@mult * .....".  Yes, that was not very obvious - my apology.

Comment: You're looking for pagination I think. [I'd start with Aaron's article](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch).

Comment: Thankyou, yes this is what I'm looking for